# script borrar carpetas segun la fecha actual

Tags: bash, shell, script, centos, asterisk

he hecho un script para borrar carpetas cuando el disco este, por ejemplo al 80%, yo lo quiero usar en centOS con asterisk.
donde las carpetas se organizan "/var/spool/monitor/2018/{01/02/.../12}"

pues hice este script que borra 2 meses atras, segun el porcentaje de espacio disponible, pero me surge la duda por ejemplo si se hace muchas llamadas en el mes 02 (febrero) y estamos en marzo y febrero o enero tiene el mayor porcentaje de espacio ocupado.¿Que hago en esta situación!!?
programare en el crontab que ejecute el script cada 1 de mes.
y si el espacio sigue siendo >80% porque las llamadas estan en febrero y no enero.

era para pediros una sugerencia de como plantearlo o que cosa he escrito mál, asi como mostraros el codigo y es super facil, lo más problable que se pueda ahorrar codigo (eso sin duda!!) pero recien empece en linux :(

```
 #!bin/bash

limit="80" ## porcentaje de espacio cuando debe actuar" ##
dir="/var/spool/asterisk/monitor"
mes=`date +%m`
anyo=`date +%Y`
ref="02";

# espacio en disco #
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}' >> temp.log

temp=$( cat temp.log)

if [ $limit -le $temp ]; then
        BORRAR=0;
        BORRAR=$((10#$mes-$ref))

                case $BORRAR in ## esto es porque rm no logra encontrar la carpeta "2" porque estan nomradas como "02".
                1) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                2) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                3) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                4) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                5) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                6) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                7) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                8) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                9) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/0"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                10) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                11) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                12) rm -rf "$dir"/"$anyo"/"$BORRAR"/
                ;;
                esac
else
        echo "nada para borrar"
fi

rm -rf temp.log

echo ___________________________________________________ >> log ## para hacer un pequeño log de cuando se ejecute el crontab ##
echo "El mes borrado fue: $BORRAR " >> log
date >> log
tail -n 22 /var/spool/mail/root >> log
df -h | grep /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}' >> log
```

porfas, decirme ideas u opiniones, creo que mi script esta siendo un poco chapucero :(

Comment: Puedes indicar si te esta dando algun error?

Comment: no me da ningun error, porque la sintaxis esta todo bien.
era para ver si me podeis dar alguna idea o como va esto para ir viendo el script.

Comment: Probablemente lo más práctico sea utilizar una herramienta como [logrotate](http://helloit.es/2012/08/rotar-archivos-de-log-con-logrotate/). Con ella conseguirás que los ficheros antiguos se vayan eliminando automáticamente, sin necesidad de tener que crear tus propios scripts _limpiadores_.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar lo siguiente en tu código:

```
# espacio en disco #
temp=$(df /dev/xvdb1 | sed s/%//g | awk '{print $5}')

if [ $limit -le $temp ]; then
  rm -rf $dir/$annio/$(printf %02 `expr $mes - $ref`)
fi
```

Utilizando `printf` harás que el resultado de la resta siempre tenga 2 digitos.

Tambien puedes utilizar [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) con el parametro `-ctime` o `-mtime` para buscar los archivos mayores a 2 meses, por ejemplo:
`find $dir -mtime -60 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;`

Puedes revisar el espacio en disco que te ocupa cada carpeta con el comando [`du`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html), por ejemplo: `du -s $dir/*` y lo puedes ordenar con `sort` de la siguiente manera: `du -s $dir/* | sort -nr`.